# Are there other ways to say "The store is farther from the motel than we expected."?

Tags: comparative

> The store is farther from the motel than we expected.

As the comparative form "farther" is a bit distant from "than" in the above sentence, it doesn't sound intuitive in relation with "than we expected" to me who is a non-native English speaker.

So I wonder whether I can use the different sentence like below.

> The store is far from the motel, more than we expected.

Any explanations or examples will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's perfectly idiomatic as is.  **farther from {something} than ...**  or **farther than {something} from...** The store is farther than we expected from the motel.  The store is farther from the motel than we expected.

Comment: I'd be inclined to add an _away_, as in: _The store is farther **away** from the motel than we expected_. Also, if you're looking to eliminate the long distance beween _farther_ and _than_, you could simply say: _We didn't expect the store to be so far from the hotel._

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for the comment. :) What change does adding an *away* make? And in real life which would be more natural or commonly used between: *The store is  farther away from the motel than we expected.* and *We didn't expect the store to be so far from the hotel.*?

Comment: It doesn't really change much, it just sounds more conversational to me. And as for those two, they sound equally natural to me. I have no idea which I'd say if I was making that statement. I might even say, "Wow! The store is further away than we thought."

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for answering. Your comment is very vividly descriptive. I could imagine the scene where you acted as an actor there! :)

Comment: @TRomano Thank you for sort them out as idiomatic patterns. I am now sure that both expressions are interchangeable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also restructure the sentence as "The store is farther than we expected from the motel." However, the original sentence you provided sounds perfectly natural. I don't think there's any reason to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may have thought in a wrong way. Then, is the sentence I wrote as an example in my question also correct and usable?: *The store is far from the motel, more than we expected.*

Comment: I think that sentence would sound fine when speaking informally. When writing, you should stick to using the original sentence, though; it sounds smoother and more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure the sentence as follows to use other comparisons than "farther":

> The trip from the motel to the store is longer than we expected.
>
> The distance from the motel to the store is bigger than we expected

Comment: Thank you. :) I have got to know other important equivalent expressions due to your answer. I am sorry that I couldn't pick your answer because I can pick only one. Both answers are equivalently nice!